# Heroku passes the build but gives Application error

Tags: django, heroku, web-deployment

Hi I am trying to deploy a website on heroku. I successfully built it on heroku. When I try to deploy it gives me the **Application Error** when I check the log this is what I am getting:

```
2021-05-30T23:43:57.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-05-30T23:44:01.169958+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=cqthub.herokuapp.com request_id=1f7f7f68-028c-4101-a61c-dee410dc2429 fwd="75.157.7.173" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-30T23:44:10.322517+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=cqthub.herokuapp.com request_id=182f7faa-e19e-4693-919f-003e0600f42c fwd="75.157.7.173" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I only mentioned 'favicon' in the footer:

```
   .....
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <!-- Footer -->
    <hr>
....
```

Can someone please tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: do you have a file called `Procfile` ?

Comment: Yes, I do I also have my ALLOWED_HOST=['*']

Comment: maybe you just didnt turn on the dyno in overview page.